# PhpStorm "Test framework quit unexpectedly"

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to setup PHPUnit tests in PhpStorm.

In **Settings > Languagees & Frameworks > PHP > PHPUnit** I have chosen the option to use Composer autoload to load PHPUnit.

In **Path to script** I have put `<path to project>/vendor/bin/phpunit`.

When I run the test suite I get the error message:

> Test framework quit unexpectedly

Answer (score 18):

***Path to script*** should be the path to the composer autoloader.

```
<path to project>/vendor/autoload.php
```

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207008615-Test-framework-quit-unexpectedly